# Rename a bunch of files to series of dates based on portion of file date?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with a couple hundred files.  They are named

- file.001.txt
- file.002.txt
- file.003.txt
- ...
- file.223.txt

I'm trying to write a powershell script to rename them all with the following logic.  Take a key date.  Say 1/1/2015.  And then based on the index number at the end of the file name iterate that date.  So you end up with:

- file.01.02.2015.txt
- file.01.03.2015.txt
- file.01.04.2015.txt
- ...
- file.08.12.2015.txt

Code sample I've stubbed out, but at a loss how to express this.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\MyFiles" -Filter
*.txt |  Foreach-Object {
    $OldName = $_.name;
    $IndexPortion = $_.name.Substring(6,3)
    $DatePortion = [datetime]::ParseExact('01/01/2015','MM/dd/yyyy',$null).AddDays($IndexPortion)
    ## ??? $NewName = $_.name -replace $IndexPortion, $DatePortion -format yyyy.MM.dd
    Rename-Item -Newname $NewName;
    Write-Output $("Renamed {0} to {1}" -f $OldName, $NewName)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $num = $_.Name.Split('.')[-2]
    $_.Name -replace $num, (Get-Date '2015-01-01').AddDays($num).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy') 
} -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\t\file.001.txt Destination: D:\t\file.01-02-2015.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\t\file.002.txt Destination: D:\t\file.01-03-2015.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\t\file.003.txt Destination: D:\t\file.01-04-2015.txt".
```

This should work if the numbers aren't elsewhere in the filenames (`file 001 test.001.txt`)

You can't just have your code putting `Rename-Item -Newname $NewName;` without saying what file to rename, and you can pipeline files into `Rename-Item` and calculate a new name with a scriptblock, so no need for the loop.

How to do the date calculation can vary, but I went with splitting the file on dots and taking the second-last entry, and Get-Date from a fixed string. Your ParseExact approach looks pretty sensible as well.

Comment: That worked like a charm thanks.  I was getting lost if all kinds of type conversions and such.  That's what I get for coming from a C# background.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should let you solve your problem.  Adjust as needed to suit your needs.

**CODE**

```
$inputs = @()
$inputs += 'file.001.txt'
$inputs += 'file.002.txt'
$inputs += 'file.100.txt'
$inputs += 'file.234.txt'
$inputs += 'file.1234.txt'

$epoch = [DateTime]::Parse("1/1/2015")
$inputs | % {
    $oldName = $_
    $pre, $id, $post = $oldName -split '\.'
    $newDate = $epoch.AddDays($id)
    $newId = $newDate.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy")
    $newName = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $pre, $newId, $post

    Write-Output "$oldName ==> $newName"
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
file.001.txt ==> file.01.02.2015.txt
file.002.txt ==> file.01.03.2015.txt
file.100.txt ==> file.04.11.2015.txt
file.234.txt ==> file.08.23.2015.txt
file.1234.txt ==> file.05.19.2018.txt
```